# Object (simple shapes) Detection in Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I've got the following image.

[image]

[Other Samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FIHK.jpg)

I want to detect the six square-shaped green portions and the one circular portion above them. I basically want a binary image with these portions marked 1 (white) and everything else 0 (black).

**What have I done so far?**

I found a range of H, S, and V within which these colors fall which works fine for a single image, but I've got multiple such images, some under different illumination (brightness) conditions and the ranges do not work in those cases. What should I do to make the thresholding as invariant to brightness as possible? Is there a different approach I should take for thresholding?

Comment: Can you add 2-3 more luminous variant casses ?

Comment: @ZdaR Added a link to other samples.

Answer (score 1):

What you did was manually analyze the values you need for thresholding for a specific image, and then apply that. What you see is that analysis done on one image doesn't necessarily fit other images.

The solution is to do the analysis automatically for each image.  This can be achieved by creating a histogram for each of the channels, and if you're working in HSV, I'm guessing that the H channel would be pretty much useless in this case.

Anyway, once you have the histograms, you should analyze the threshold using something like Lloyd-Max, which is basically a K-Means type clustering of intensities.   This should give the centroids for the intensity of the white background, and the other colors.  Then you choose the threshold based on the cluster standard deviation.

For example, in the image you gave above, the histogram of the S channel looks like:

[image: Histogram of S channel]

You can see the large blob near 0 is the white background that has the lowest saturation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you elaborate a bit on how to cluster using Lloyd-Max and is there a way to do this in using OpenCV?

Comment: You can use K-Means with K=2  (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html).  Just convert the saturation values to floating point and pass the entire saturation channel as the data.  It should give you the centroids of the background and the other colors.  Then you can take the pixels that belong to the background (from the output labels) and calculate the background standard deviation to decide what the threshold should be.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on, "calculate the background standard deviation to decide what the threshold should be"?

Comment: If the group of pixels belonging to the background have a saturation with a mean of M and a standard deviation of S, you can set a threshold around  M+c*S   where you can tune the value of c until you get the result you want on a set of benchmark images.